# Reverseing a string in java

Tags: java, string, reverse

if i need to reverse a given string like " HELLO WORLD " to become

"DLROW OLLEH "

so how can do that ? and if there is any  function that do the same what is it ?

Comment: i'm sure this question would be asked n number of times.

Comment: Do some research, you'll be surprised, this gets asked ALOT...